# Change cell color according to values below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking all over the place for a way to change the color of a cell according to the value of a the cell below in Google spreadsheet.

Each cell within the range `A1:F1` needs to change color if the value of the immediate cell  below is > or < or = to 0.

So `A1` will always look at `A2`, `B1` will always look at `B2` and so on. In my table I might need a random cell range with a value below it, change color. I would also like to use named ranges as this will never change.

I would love to provide a code sample but the thing is that I don't even know where to start after function `onEdit()` and setting what I think the variables should be.

```js
function onEdit(){
  var e = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = e.getActiveSheet().getName('Basic');
  var items = e.getRangeByName('avgt1v1name').getValues();
  var values = e.getRangeByName('avg1t1b').getValues();
```

I don't know if I should use an IF statement or go for a loop with FOR or WHILE.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
MoExius

Answer (score 0):

My guess...

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Basic');
  var values = ss.getRangeByName('avg1t1b').getValues();

  var nameRange = ss.getRangeByName('avgt1v1name');
  var rowIndex = nameRange.getRowIndex();

  for (var i = 0; i <= values[0].length -1; i++) {
    var col = i + 1;
    var cell = values[0][i];
    if (cell != '' && (cell <= 0 || cell > 0) ) {
      nameRange.getCell(rowIndex, col ).setBackgroundColor('red');
      }
    else {nameRange.getCell(rowIndex, col ).setBackgroundColor('white');}
  }
};
```

Doesn't work when numerical zero is in the spreadsheet for some reason. [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnJTymuE8awLdHRXZUlVVjZTV1hNeHRGQ0liT3Z4eWc).